# react native platform dependent rendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i'm developing a cross platform app and would like to render a checkbox in android and a switch in IOS. For this i'm trying to use the Platform.select functionality from the react native documentation from the following page https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-module.

```
import {
   Modal,       
   SwitchIOS,
   Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';


class MeetingDisplay extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const PlatformSpecificCheckBox = Platform.select({
            ios: () => require('SwitchIOS'),
            android: () => require('CheckBox'),
         })();
     }
 ....
```

Everytime i try to run my app on either a device or simulator get "unable to locate SwitchIOS" or "unable to locate Checkbox" if i switch the order of the statements. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**

Changed the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It worked for me:

```
const PlatformSpecificCheckBox = Platform.select({
        ios: () => SwitchIOS,
        android: () => CheckBox,
     });
```